# after wordpress configuring htaccess it gives not found

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I've got wordpress installed, and something got messed up while it did it. I can't make it so if I go to www.website.com/something it would load it, and it throws a not found error message. I've tried changing the way WordPress uses the htaccess files and now it loads from index.html/something but I would like other files to load as if I just type in the name of them after the "/".

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ./index.php [L] 
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

php_value upload_max_filesize 512M
php_value post_max_size 512M
php_value max_execution_time 500
php_value max_input_time 500
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop changing the `.htaccess`, and make sure everything is back to default. You can leave the php_value settings.

In WP, the URL structure is managed by permalinks. Go to wp-admin -> settings -> permalinks.

Setting the permalink structure like this:

```
http://yourdomain.com/%postname%/
```

(select Postname in General settings)

The page/post title will be used in the URL.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, and I also wrote in the original post that I tried doing it and even then it didn't work and gave a not found error.

Comment: well, you orginal question is very confusing. What do you mean by:  _I would like other files to load as if I just type in the name of them after the "/"._ ?? Do you mean real files, or do you mean WP pages/posts?

Comment: Both, as both won't load anyway.

Comment: Did you try setting htaccess back to default, go to permalinks and re-save the settings? That last step (re-save) is important. Also, if you go to a post/page (in wp-admin) you can see the url below the title? How is it formatted?

Comment: Yup. this shouldn't happen anyway as my old installation of wordpress was exactly the same and it did work.